# I wanted to make a page which is readonly but when clicked on edit the user should be able to edit it

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have basic user details page, that I display to user when they login. Now once they click on edit they should be able to edit their information on the same page.

I am doing this for the first time I know how to do it in java or php... but apex is very new to me. please  provide me with some pointers and examples.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a custom vf page that you show to users when the login then use apex:outputtext to show read only fields, when a boolean editable is false 
For example:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!field}" rendered="{! IF(editable,false,true)}" />
```

and when they click on click on edit button(which should be custom), just set editable as true and have another display component like:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!field}" rendered="{!IF(editable,true,false)}" />
```

**Update**

As @dphil pointed out you can even use:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!field}" rendered="{!editable}" />
```

Comment: Not sure if you knew but **< apex:inputField value={!field} rendered={!editable}>** is the exact same as **< apex:inputField value={!field} rendered={!IF(editable,true,false)}>**.  I tend to code by the simpler the better.

Comment: @dphil that's right and a good point, but since the person has said that he is new to apex and wanted some pointers I thought to carry on with the IF condition to have a consistency in the answer.
But again yes, your comment does add simplicity to the example

Comment: beware that if OP is using AJAX rerender="xx" that `xx` had better be some component on the page that is always present (like the form or some outputPanel) as otherwise the rerender wont rerender something that started off invisible - see the classic Bob Buzzard post : http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the `inlineEditSupport` tag. Here is the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm).

Example

```
<apex:outputField value="{!field}">
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />
</apex:outputField>
```